# How to create a csv file from a Python cell in Jupyter notebook in Win10?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, windows-10

I am going through the examples in "Python for Data Analysis" by Wes McKinney in a Jupyter Notebook, and I got stuck on the following Python code snippet:

```
!cat examples/csv_mindex.csv
key1, key2, value1, value2
one, a, 1, 2
one, b, 3, 4
one, c, 5, 6
one, d, 7, 8
two, a, 9, 10
two, b, 11, 12
two, c, 13, 14
two, d, 15, 16
```

How can I get this code to run in a Windows 10 operating system? How would I write out the path where the file should be saved if the directory is  **c:\testfolder**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't own the book, but the usage of `cat` suggests that that snippet is not meant to create, but rather to *show the contents* of an *already existing* `csv_mindex.csv`. What you put in the question are both the input *and the output* of invoking `cat` from a Jupyter notebook.

To "translate" this in the Windows shell, if the file *already exists* you can print it from Jupyter with `type` as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600428/4240413) by putting in a cell

```
!type csv_mindex.csv
```

May you want to *create* such a file, you could **use the magic function `%%file`** and execute in a cell

```
%%file csv_mindex.csv
key1,key2,value1,value2
one, a, 1, 2 
one, b, 3, 4
one, c, 5, 6 
one, d, 7, 8 
two, a, 9, 10  
two, b, 11, 12  
two, c, 13, 14 
two, d, 15, 17
```

That should create the desired file, and also work cross-platform (so also e.g. on GNU/Linux).

May you need to write the file in an `examples` directory, you could first create the dir with

```
!mkdir examples
```

and then use `%%file examples\csv_mindex.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is using the Linux program `cat` which prints out files. On windows, you can run

```
type examples/csv_mindex.csv
```

in the `C:/testfolder` from the command line.